# FormCollection to expandoObject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way I can copy a `FormCollection` form into an `ExpandoObject`?

I will get a post from a third party company. Others third party will use get and they all end up in a method that takes a dynamic input parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, not the most elegant code (probably better ways to do it), but one way could be something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(FormCollection collection)
{
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>) expando;

    foreach (var item in collection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, value => collection[value]))
    {
        dictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
    // your expando will be populated here ...
    // do awesomeness
}
```

I hope this helps (at least it might give you an idea).

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant. I'll accept your answer in a couple of days if noone comes up with something like a oneliner (or two)

Comment: Why the foreach? Why not just: dictionary = collection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, value => collection[value]);

Comment: Because the dictionary is actually the expando, so you need to copy the data in it, you can cast it back to an actual expando.

Comment: @user1711409 You can hide this in an extension method (`ToExpando()` or something), but you can't cast the dictionary back to an `ExpandoObject`. Honestly, I hope I'm making sense, I'm terrible at explanations :)

Comment: @user1711409 Anytime :) Glad I could help.