# How to pass a select option value from a view to a controller in MVC5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "APIController",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <select id="Segmentation" name="Segmentation">
    @foreach (var item in Model.listofSegments)
    {
        <option>@item</option>
    }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

Model:

```
public class SegmentRepository
{
    public List<String> GetSegmentation()
    {
        //I have the values in this
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class APIController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        SegmentRepository segment = new SegmentRepository();
        mymodel.listofSegments = segment.GetSegmentation();
        String roleValue1 = formCollection["Segmentation"];
        return View(mymodel);
    }
}
```

I am not able to get the select option value in `roleValue1`.

I want to take the value from `roleValue1` and use it to trigger another dropdown in my view.

Comment: Have you want to use cascading HTML `select`? If my guess is right, consider using client-side JS which triggers AJAX call to the controller action & return response data from there (possibly using partial view or AJAX `success` which can `append` option elements for second dropdown).

Answer (score 4):

**View Code**

```
@model dynamic
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ddl";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>ddl</h2>

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionPostData", "Demo", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <select name="Segmentation">
        <option selected value="0">---Select---</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
        }
    </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
</div>
```

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult Ddl()
{
    var segmentList = new List<listofSegments>();
    listofSegments segmentItem;
    var strArr = new string[] { "Jaipur", "Kota", "Bhilwara", "Udaipur", "Chitorgar", "Ajmer", "Jodhpur" };
    for (int index = 0; index < strArr.Length; index++)
    {
        segmentItem = new listofSegments();
        segmentItem.Text = strArr[index];
        segmentItem.Value = (index + 1).ToString();
        segmentList.Add(segmentItem);
    }
    return View(segmentList);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionPostData(string Segmentation)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Ddl");
}

public class listofSegments
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you look at the syntax of `<select> Tag` its like this

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

you have to set the value of each option but in your case you are just providing the text not the value. So it should be like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "APIController",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <select id="Segmentation" name="Segmentation">
    @foreach (var item in Model.listofSegments)
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option> //if the value is same as text
    }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you have 2 issues here:

1) Your `option` tag inside `select` element requires `value` attribute to be POST-ed with `FormCollection` instance.

2) `BeginForm` should use proper controller name with `HttpPost` attribute marked on corresponding controller action method (by default controller action method uses `HttpGet`).

The proper usage should be like this:

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "API", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <select id="Segmentation" name="Segmentation">
    @foreach (var item in Model.listofSegments)
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option>
    }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class APIController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        SegmentRepository segment = new SegmentRepository();
        mymodel.listofSegments = segment.GetSegmentation();
        String roleValue1 = formCollection["Segmentation"];

        return View(mymodel);
    }
}
```

If you want to pass `FormCollection` into dynamic `ExpandoObject`, there is a post to consider with: [FormCollection to expandoObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275533/formcollection-to-expandoobject).

Additionally if you want to pass `select` option value to insert option values into other `select` element at the same view page, you need jQuery AJAX callback (`$.ajax`) in client-side with passed data & use `append` method to add `option` elements after `success` response.

Answer (score 0):

you must change:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "APIController", FormMethod.Post))
```

to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "API", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Well the name of my Controller is APIController

Comment: in your case only API's is necessary.